# Unit Testing a Class Wrapping a Container

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nunit

My class wraps a C# List to extend it with input validation. I test the simple case of calling the AddRows() method with valid data and check items have been added to the internal list.

It seems to me that my test should only care if AddRange() was called on the List, however I actually have to manually check these elements have been added to the underlying list. I feel this is out of scope of the test as it is testing functionality provided by the List and not the ManagedList.

I could resolve this by injecting the List as a dependency to the ManagedList class and substituting in a mocked list in my test that validates if AddRange() was called with the correct data. However having to pass a List as a dependency into my ManagedList class seems a bit over the top.

I feel like I have 2 options:

- Test functionality already provided by the internal List
- Inject the list as a dependency so it can be mocked

Am I missing an obvious third option here? If not, which one of the above is the preferable option?

**In summary**

**Managed List Class**

```
class ManagedList
{
    private readonly List<Dictionary<string, object>> _data = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> GetData()
    {
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>(_data);
    }

    public void AddRows(List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows)
    {
        if (rows.Any(row => !row.ContainsKey("id")))
            throw new Exception("All rows must have an id");

        _data.AddRange(rows);
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
[Test]
public void AddRowsSucceedsWithId()
{
    var managedList = new ManagedList();
    var row = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"id", "Item1"}};
    var rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>> {row, row, row};

    CollectionAssert.IsNotSupersetOf(managedList.GetData(), rows);

    managedList.AddRows(rows);

    CollectionAssert.IsSupersetOf(managedList.GetData(), rows);
}
```

Comment: Why not try combining both.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead change the dictionary type to use an interface to enforce your requirement

[image]